# .NET Core google token validation middleware

Tags: .net-core

I have client application what is writen using Angularjs and .Net Core WebAPI backend. User's authenticate using Google sign-in where we get the token. This token is sent to backend with every API request where its has to be validated.

Is there a middleware or how could i create middleware what would validate the token?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is: *Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google*

which you can install with:

> dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google

and then configure the middleware in your startup.cs:

```
app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOptions()
{
    ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"],
    ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"]
});
```

I'd suggest you read the extremely helpful and easy to follow Microsoft guide for asp.net core social authentication here:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/

and the Google specific walkthrough here:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins